# generate plot of world rivers map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

Looking to create a plot in R of the rivers (and lakes?) of the world where they are the only lines. Ie it should be nothing but rivers, land and sea is all one color (white) while rivers (and lakes) are another. Any tips? Rworldmap or ggplot the way to go?

Comment: It's unclear if you're looking for a data set or a way to plot the data. In either case, this is not a proper SO question. If you have a specific question about implementing this plot, please rephrase your question and show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that could be just:

```
require(mapdata)
map('world', interior=F,col="darkgray")
map('rivers', add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

[image]

or for just rivers:

```
 map('world', interior=F,col="white")
 map('rivers', add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: For your second example, did you mean: `map('lakes',`  ???

Comment: @ryyker A typo, I meant 'rivers'. This solution gives you some lakes too, but not sure how to map lakes-only.